# Extract and group by type env variables from k8s deployments with jq

Tags: json, bash, kubernetes, jq

I am trying to extract the list of k8s deployment environment variables and merge the environment variables into a group of categories using jq and regex.

**Example**

k8s deployment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: test
  name: test
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: test
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: test
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: server
        env:
        - name: DB_MAINDB_HOST
          value: maindb.example.com
        - name: DB_MAINDB_DATABASE
          value: test
        - name: DB_MAINDB_USERNAME
          value: username
        - name: DB_MAINDB_PASSWORD
          value: password
        - name: ES_HOST
          value: es-client.example.com
        - name: ES_INDEX
          value: test
        - name: REDIS_HOST
          value: redis.example.com
        image: bustbox
```

**Desired output**

```
{
  "namespace": "default",
  "name": "test",
  "databases": [
    {
      "name": "DB_MAINDB_DATABASE",
      "value": "test"
    },
    {
      "name": "DB_MAINDB_HOST",
      "value": "maindb.example.com"
    },
    {
      "name": "DB_MAINDB_PASSWORD",
      "value": "password"
    },
    {
      "name": "DB_MAINDB_USERNAME",
      "value": "username"
    }
  ],
  "redis": [
    {
      "name": "REDIS_HOST",
      "value": "redis.example.com"
    }
  ],
  "elasticsearch": [
    {
      "name": "ES_HOST",
      "value": "es-client.example.com"
    },
    {
      "name": "ES_INDEX",
      "value": "test"
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried to do this with the following command:

```
kubectl get deployments test -o json | jq -r '. |
        {namespace: .metadata.namespace,
        name: .metadata.name,
        databases: (.spec.template.spec.containers[].env | [ map(.) | .[] | select(.name | contains ("DB"))] | sort_by(.name)),
        redis: (.spec.template.spec.containers[].env | [ map(.) | .[] | select(.name | contains ("REDIS"))] | sort_by(.name)),
        elasticsearch: (.spec.template.spec.containers[].env | [ map(.) | .[] | select(.name | test("^(ES_).") or contains ("ELASTIC"))] | sort_by(.name)),
        }'
```

I am looking for a slightly more elegant solution to my problem and, in addition, want to have the ability to manage a mapping of the categories with the relevant regex as additional input to the command.

Thanks!

Comment: You can just drop the useless `. |`, convert `[ map(.) | .[] | select(…)]` to just `map(select(…))`, and factor out `.metadata` and `.spec.template.spec.containers[].env` respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one rewrite with several duplicates factored out. Decide for yourself if this meets your requirement for elegance:

```sh
(
  .metadata | {namespace, name}
) + (
  .spec.template.spec.containers[].env | {
    databases: map(select(.name | contains ("DB"))),
    redis: map(select(.name | contains ("REDIS"))),
    elasticsearch: map(select(.name | test("^(ES_).") or contains ("ELASTIC")))
  }
  | map_values(sort_by(.name))
)
```

Additionally, you could bring the sort up front to sort the unfiltered array just once:

```sh
(
  .metadata | {namespace, name}
) + (
  .spec.template.spec.containers[].env | sort_by(.name) | {
    databases: map(select(.name | contains ("DB"))),
    redis: map(select(.name | contains ("REDIS"))),
    elasticsearch: map(select(.name | test("^(ES_).") or contains ("ELASTIC")))
  }
)
```